Why is react rerendering when the primitive state isn't changing?
Consider this very basic example of a react app:
function App(props) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      setCounter(counter+1);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log('render', counter);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

One thing to immediately note here is that there is a bug inside the useEffect. Because we didn't pass in any dependencies, our event handler is stale and will only increment counter the first time we click on the document. This is to be expected.
The strange part is that this is what the console output looks like after clicking on the document twice:
render 0
render 1
render 1

Why is it rerendering on the second click if the counter state didn't actually change? Essentially, setCounter(1) looks like it is causing a rerender when counter is already 1.
React.StrictMode is off, so what is causing this strange behaviour?

Does this answer your question? React hooks useState setValue still rerender one more time when value is equal. As to why it's expected behavior, see: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14810#issuecomment-462089702

Btw, replacing setCounter(counter+1) with setCounter(1) still yields the same output
